# How to create this gesture effect animation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

How I can create this type of sweep animation using gesture or other method in android studing using java.

Effect: https://ibb.co/hKJjen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So for the swiping cards you'll have to use this library**

> https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack

When user will touches/swipes the cards there will be a white dot which acts as a pointer just like how you'r attached example shows. Click the below link and you'll get the right code implementation for it!

> http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-custom-touch-view-with-callback.html

Comment: Thank you, its help me a lot.